# How to make edges appear in a graph when adjacency matrix value is beyond a particular threshold?

Tags: r, graphs

I've created a graph from an adjacency matrix using the igraph package but I want edges to appear in the graph only when the value in the adjacency matrix is beyond a particular threshold. Using the present method I am getting all the edges which have non zero weights.

```
set.seed(42)
iris_matrix <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])
image(iris_matrix)
g<-cor(iris_matrix)
library(igraph)
R<-graph.adjacency(g, mode=c("undirected"), weighted=TRUE, diag=FALSE, add.colnames=NULL, add.rownames=NULL)
plot(R)
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 7 is what you need:

```
set.seed(42)
iris_matrix <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])
image(iris_matrix)
g<-cor(iris_matrix)
library(igraph)
R<-graph.adjacency(g, mode=c("undirected"), weighted=TRUE, diag=FALSE, add.colnames=NULL, add.rownames=NULL)
R[R > thresh] <- 0 
plot(R)
```

Comment: Used your method @kasra manshaei but got the following error : Error in inherits(v, "igraph.vs") : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Check your R matrix after line 6. Whatever it is should be also after line 7 (double, int, ...). then converting it to this type will solve. Unfortunately I do not have access to R otherwise I would have sent you the code.

Comment: It's a 4*4 matrix @Kasra Manshaei, where do i find the 6th line :P

Comment: :)))) I mean 6th line in the code above dude ... not inside your matrix